# Definition of linear independence for infinite set of vectors

Tags: functional-analysis

"A set $\mathbf{A}$ (with not necesseraly finite cardinality) is said to be linearly independent if all of his finite subsets are linearly independent"
why is it not possible to substitute "finite subsets" with "proper subsets" in the aforementioned definition?

Comment: Because some of the proper subsets would be infinite and you cannot define what being an infinite linearly independent set of vectors appealing to some infinite subset being linearly independent (would be a vicious circle). You have to define it in terms of something you have previously defined, like independence of finite sets of vectors.

Comment: What makes the definition wrong: the fact that there is a cycle or that this cycle could be never ending in some cases (uncountable set)?

Comment: Not exactly. The point is that you cannot define a new concept in terms of itself. You cannot say “something has the Property P if something else has the same property. How can one ever check that property?

Comment: It is like saying “an object is blue if any piece of it is blue” Have I defined what “blue “ means? No. I should appeal to something else like the wavelength of the light reflected by the object.